# submitting form to database not working

Tags: php, mysql, html

So I'm tired, have been trying this for hours now and still can't find why it won't work. Knowing me, it's probably some stupid error I've made somewhere. Anyhoo, I have a form that I need to be able to submit, whereupon the texts entered get inserted into a database. However, whenever I press submit, it simply goes back to the main page and doesn't insert anything. Code is here:

```
//New Memory
<?php 
if ($x == 'new') {
?>

<a href="pensieve_elizabeth.php"><- Back</a>
<center>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
          <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
             <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted" />

             <p><b>Add Memory </b></p>
             <p>Title:<br> 
             <input class="textfield" name="title" maxlength="55" style="width:325px;">
             <br>
             Memory: <br>  
             <textarea class="textfield" name="entry" value="entry" id="entry" cols="30" rows="10" style="width:325px;"></textarea><br>

             <input type="submit" value=" Submit " />

             <input type="checkbox" name="private" value="1"> Private 

             <p>What thread does the memory belong to? (optional):<textarea class="textfield" name="links" rows="1" style="width:325px;"></textarea><br />

         </form>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</center>

<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

  $title = trim(addslashes(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']))));
  $entry = trim(addslashes(strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['entry']))));
  $private = $_POST['private'];
  $links = $_POST['links'];

  if (empty($title)) message("Please give the memory a title.");
  if (empty($entry)) message("Your memory is empty.");

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO pensieve SET uid = '$userID', subject = '$title', memory = '$entry', dateline = '".date()."', private = '$private', links = '$links'") or die(mysql_error());

  message("You have successfully submitted this memory to your pensieve!","/pensieve_elizabeth.php");
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not move your isset block before the echo?

Comment: aah yes, I had that before and it didn't work, so I copied another script in moving it down :/

Comment: $PHP_SELF just refers to the current url

Comment: You also might want to just write html instead of having PHP output a html string.

Comment: @Elizabeth, can you `var_dump()` it to make sure?

Comment: Also when you submit the form does $x equals "new" ;)

Comment: is the INSERT query correct? I have not anything like that before

Comment: @Radu, just because I haven't worked out the var_dump() yet, how would I go about doing that correctly?

Comment: @Elizabeth, just `<?php var_dump($PHP_SELF) ?>` anywhere so you can see its output. It should print out the contents of the `$PHP_SELF` variable.

Comment: Thanks! var_dump(/pensieve_elizabeth.php); it doesn't have the x= at the end

Comment: @Elizabeth, does using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$PHP_SELF` solve the problem?

Comment: no, it makes the page unable to load :s

Comment: @Elizabeth, with an error message?

Comment: just Chrome's placeholder for what usually are parsing errors like a missed ; or >. In Internet Explorer a blank page. Although the submit does work if I put in action=\"/pensieve_elizabeth.php?x=new\" albeit it loads the whole page again and has the success message at the bottom

Comment: also @Любомир Маринов how would I ensure that $x is set to new?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong.

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO pensieve SET uid = '$userID', subject = '$title', memory = '$entry', dateline = '".date()."', private = '$private', links = '$links'") or die(mysql_error());
```

must be

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pensieve(uid, subject, memory, dateline, private, links) values('$userID', '$title', '$entry', '".date()."', '$private', '$links')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: How did I missed that, oh god, I'll edit my answer anyways nice one

Comment: Your previous answer was better... `INSERT INTO ... SET` is [valid MySQL syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

Comment: edited that back in now, it still doesn't work :/ thanks though, I'll remember the format for the future!

Comment: I always use die("something") function to trace where the code breaks :) try to die("posted") right after if(isset($_POST)) statement :)

Answer (score 1):

First do set the following at the top of your script

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This will tell you everything about what goes wrong and on what line.

Second, I don't understand why are you doing this

```
 INSERT INTO pensieve SET uid = '$userID', subject = '$title', 
 memory = '$entry', dateline = '".date()."', 
  private = '$private', links = '$links'");
```

You're using INSERT and UPDATE syntax together

if you want to insert use

```
 "INSERT INTO pensieve ('uid', 'subject', 'memory', 'dateline', 
     'private', 'links')  VALUES ('$userID','$title','$entry','".date()."',
   '$private', '$links'");
```

The following will directly insert a row irrespective of duplicate values in individual rows

if you want to update use

```
    "UPDATE pensieve SET uid = '$userID', subject = '$title', memory = '$entry', 
  dateline = '".date()."', private = '$private', links = '$links'" 
   WHERE 'something' = 'something_value' ";
```

Altogether do

```
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pensive.......");
    if(!$result){
       mysql_error();
    }
```

Comment: I had that at first and when it didn't work I thought I'd try this instead. Changed it back now though, but it still doesn't work

Comment: the problem is somewhere else in your code then. It would be helpful if you could post your `message(...)` method

Answer (score 0):

```
    Add these two lines to the top of your script, this will show any sort of errors in the script or query execution:

    ini_set("display_errors","on");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    And for the data not getting inserted:
    check your query if all the mandatory/not null values are passed in the query or not. For example - I do not see userid being set in your script.  

   Your insert query syntax is wrong - the correct syntax is 
 insert into table1(col1,col2,col3) values(val1,val2,val3);

so your query would be :

$sql ="INSERT INTO pensieve(uid,subject,memory,dateline,private,links) values ('$userID','$title', '$entry','". date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())."', '$private', '$links'";

if you want to update then :

$SQL = "UPDATE pensieve SET uid = '$userID', subject = '$title', memory = '$entry', dateline = '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time())."', private = '$private', links = '$links'";
```